# Vaadin Calendar events not shown if overnight

Tags: vaadin

In my vaadin project there is the possibility to create events that are shown by the calendar. It does works, except when the event is overnight, let's say the night from 23th to 24th, and the calendar shows as only day the 24th. In this case the part of the event that belongs to the 24th is supposed to be shown, but it is not. When I switch to weekly view, the event is shown properly. Here is the function where I get the data and use a container for the calendar:

```
/* Fill Calendar from database */
void updateData() { 
    final BeanItemContainer<TypeReservationEvent> container =
            new BeanItemContainer<TypeReservationEvent>(TypeReservationEvent.class);
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("roomParent",chosenRoom);
    String query = "SELECT DISTINCT res FROM EntityReservation res, EntityRoom r, EntityTable rt WHERE res.tableId = rt.id "
            + "AND rt.roomParent =:roomParent";
    reservationList = facade.list(query, parameters);
    for(EntityReservation rt : reservationList) {
            container.addBean(new TypeReservationEvent(rt));
    }
    container.sort(new Object[]{"start"}, new boolean[]{true});
    cal.setContainerDataSource(container, "caption",
            "description", "start", "end", "styleName");

    // Force calendar to refresh
    if(selectCalViewType.getValue() == chooseWeeklyView) {
        setViewType(calViewType.DAILY);
        setViewType(calViewType.WEEKLY);
    } else if (selectCalViewType.getValue() == chooseDailyView) {
        setViewType(calViewType.WEEKLY);
        setViewType(calViewType.DAILY);
    }
}
```

TIA

Edit: Note that the missing event has no div of class "v-calendar-event" in contrast to normal events. So I think it't not a pure css problem but for some reason the calendar decides to not show the event at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it with following style. But I am sure there is a better solution...

```
.v-calendar-weekly-longevents {

    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Tried it (both - see below), didnt work. It's indeed similar, but in my case the event doesn't show up at all in calendar in contrast to other events that has div of class "v-calendar-event". I will add this to my question.
btw. In vaadin Forum you wrote "display: inline-block !important;", guess you have a type here?